# ¿Cómo ponerle un color con intermitente a una celda de datagridView segun el valor del campo, C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Tengo la siguiente tabla en donde tengo que marcar en color rojo en donde la columna de total sea igual o mayor a 3, si es igual a 2 debe marcar en color naranja y si es igual a 1 se queda en blanco:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizo el siguiente código en el evento de CELLFORMATING del DataGrid:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Total")
    {
        if (e.Value != null)
        {
            if (e.Value.GetType() != typeof(System.DBNull))
            {
                //reportes 3 o mayor
                if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Value) >= 3)
                {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
                //reportes igual a 2
                if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Value) == 2)
                {
                    e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange;
                    e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pero quiero que tenga una intermitencia en esos colores o que cambie constantemente de rojo a otro color cumpliendo la condición ya mencionada,
de antemano gracias.

Comment: Cuál es el problema, qué error tienes?

Comment: Uno de los problemas que tienes es no manejar el caso cuando el valor sea menor a 2. Con un `switch` resolverías varios de tus problemas

Comment: O sea que si la celda tiene un valor 3 puede ser rojo, verde, azul o cualquier otro color?

Comment: solo quiero agregar un tipo de intermitente(tipo de parpadeo) a las celdas para que no se quede fijo en color rojo o en naranja

Comment: Es Windows Form?

Comment: si windows form

Comment: Hola toni, podrias decirme si la respuesta dada te fue util y en caso de que haya resuelto tu problema marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Primero te aclaro que solamente voy a tener en cuenta las celdas cuyo **total sea >= 3** y voy a alternar entre los **colores rojos y azul**, ya que es solo un ejemplo que te pongo, para el resto de las columnas, adaptarías este código, lo importante es que te lleves la idea.

Aclarado lo anterior entonces debemos hacer uso de un **Timer** y poner en su **evento Tick** el siguiente código:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
   if (row.Cells["Total"].Value != null && Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["Total"].Value) >= "3")
   {
      if (rojo) //variable global de tipo bool que se inicializa en true
      {
         dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Cells["Total"].Style.BackColor = Color.Blue;
         dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Cells["Total"].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
         rojo = false;
      }
      else if (!rojo)
      {
         dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Cells["Total"].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
         dataGridView2.Rows[row.Index].Cells["Total"].Style.ForeColor = Color.White;
         rojo = true;
      }
   }
}
```

Un **Timer** es un componente que se ejecuta cada cierto intervalo de tiempo, en este ejemplo se configuró para que se ejecutara cada **3 segundos**, para hacer esto se van a las propiedades del **Timer** y en la **propiedad Interval** se le da el valor **3000** (**3** **segundos**), ya que se expresa en milisegundos y también se pone en **true** la **propiedad Enabled** para que el **Timer** se ejecute.

Aquí ejecutamos un **ciclo foreach** que recorrerá cada fila del **DataGridView** y preguntará por cada fila si el valor de la **celda total** cumple con la condición deseada.

De cumplirse esta condición preguntamos si la **variable rojo** tiene como valor **true**, esta es una **variable global** que debemos inicializar en **true**.

Si la **variable rojo** es **true** entonces ponemos a la celda de color azul y le damos a la **variable rojo** el valor **false**, entonces el **Timer** volverá a ejecutarse dentro de **3** **segundos**, pasados los **3** **segundos** se harán de nuevo las mismas comprobaciones pero esta vez como la **variable rojo** es **false** se le dará a la celda indicada el color rojo, y así sucesivamente se irán alternando los colores.