# Pintar row de DataGridView dependiendo del valor de celdas

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datagridview

Tengo un `DatagridView` que me muestra las líneas de un albarán.
Entre otras, unas de las columnas de este `DGV`, son unidades y 'series servidas', tengo un `textbox` para la entrada de series.
Al entrar una serie de un articulo, en ese `Row` se actualizará el valor de la celda 'series servidas' a +1.
El criterio es que cuando 'series servidas' sea 0, el `row` será rojo, cuando sea >0 naranja y cuando sea = unidades verde.

Lo primero que se me viene a la cabeza, es que cada vez que entre una serie, recorra el `grid` y registro por registro mire esos dos valores y pinte en consecuencia, pero algo me dice que ese no esa ni de lejos la mejor forma de hacerlo.
¿Hay algún método mejor de hacerlo?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Mira el código de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/499407/15301). Hace exactamente lo que pides

Comment: Exactamente lo que necesitaba, gracias.